# JFreeChart TimeSeries Chart remove days with no value

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, time-series

Is there a simple way to remove days with no value?
Here is some of my data
`12-04-2012 => 15

13-04-2012 => 12

15-04-2012 => 10

16-04-2012 => 5`

In chart 14-04-2012 is painted. I mean, theres a longer line between 13-04 and 15-04. Is it possible to have equal gaps between values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an TimeSeries (org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries
)? if so consider using a CategoryDataset (org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries)

```
   private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    dataset.addValue(15, "Series 1", "12-04-2012");
    dataset.addValue(12, "Series 1", "13-04-2012");
    dataset.addValue(10, "Series 1", "15-04-2012");
    dataset.addValue(5,  "Series 1",  "16-04-2012");
    return dataset;
}
```

Using this data with JFreeChart *Line Chart Demo 8* you will get this:

[image]

Ommiting the 14th

Comment: Yes, i'm using org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries . Your chart look's nice, give a try and let you know:)